# Exodus 7:22; 8:7 why did not the Egyptian Magicians try to antagonize the effect of Moses' miracles?

Tags: exodus, hebrew-bible

Exodus 7:22 DRB:

> And the magicians of the Egyptians with their enchantments did in like manner: and Pharao's heart was hardened, neither did he hear them, as the Lord had commanded.

Exodus 8:7 DRB:

> And the magicians also by their enchantments did in like manner, and the brought forth frogs upon all the land of Egypt

Exodus 8:18 DRB:

> And the magicians with their enchantments practiced in like manner, to bring forth sciniphs, and they could not and there were sciniphs as well on men as on beasts.

The Egyptian Magicians in Exodus 7:22; 8:7, as it seems, did miracles like that of Moses, while in Exodus 8:18 they were trying to antagonize the effect of Moses' miracle.

Why in Exodus 7:22; Exodus 8:7 they did not try to antagonize the effect of Moses' miracles?

Answer (score 2):

**Why did the magicians not 'antagonize' the effect of Moses' miracles ?**

I take it that your words can bear the meaning 'overturn' the effect and that is what I assume in the following :

No doubt, had they been able to, they would have done so. Much to the pleasure of Pharaoh and to their own personal advantage and standing in the kingdom.

Obviously, they did not have the power to overturn what God had done.

All they could do was to *mimic what God had done.*

Their power was very limited.